# Does a Double Weapon work with Two-weapon feats?

Tags: dnd-4e, two-weapon-fighting, feat-qualifications, double-weapons

Would the benefits from the feats: Two-weapon Fighting, Two-weapon Opening, Two-weapon Defense, etc... apply to a character that uses a Double Axe, Double Sword or Double Scimitar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes.

You get exactly the same benefits as if you were wielding two one-handed weapons.

> Wielding a double weapon is like wielding a weapon in each hand. [Adventurer's Vault 10, identical in [online Compendium entry](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=583)]

There are a couple of weirdnesses with regard to Small characters, the `stout` keyword, and so forth, but as D&D is an exception-based system and none of those exceptions seem to be commonly prone to confusion, it would be tedious and unnecessarily listy to go into them here.