# Can the feat Two-Weapon defense be taken with a double weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, feat-qualifications

Note: This question has been answered for D&D 4e, but I'm asking if this also works in D&D 3.5 since the systems tend to differ significantly over different editions. ( [Does a Double Weapon work with Two-weapon feats?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/23281/does-a-double-weapon-work-with-two-weapon-feats) )

So can a Two-weapon feat be used with a double weapon in 3.5? Same question also goes for the feat "Ambidexterity".

Answer (score 2):

For the purposes of the Two-Weapon Defense feat in particular,

> #### Two-Weapon Defense [General]
>
> [...]
>
> **Benefit:** When wielding a double weapon [...] you gain a +1 shield bonus to your AC.

It doesn’t get any more explicit than that.

Ambidexterity was a feat in 3e, which was removed from the game in 3.5e. It is no longer necessary at all; its benefits are just the default for 3.5e characters (the penalties for two-weapon fighting were larger in 3e).

As for other “Two-Weapon” feats, well, they can be explicit about it, like Two-Weapon Defense is. Or they can piggyback off of the general two-weapon fighting rules, as Two-Weapon Fighting, Improved Two-Weapon Fighting, and Greater Two-Weapon Fighting do. Or they can be... a semi-undefined case.

For the sake of clarity, note that above I referred to “two-weapon fighting” and “Two-Weapon Fighting.” A terrible choice on Wizards’ part, I’m afraid, to name things so confusingly. When I say “two-weapon fighitng,” I am referring to the [two-weapon fighting specal attack](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#twoWeaponFighting) that anyone can use. When I say Two-Weapon Fighting, I am referring to the [Two-Weapon Fighting feat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#twoWeaponFighting) you can take to lower the attack penalties when using the two-weapon fighting special attack. So, the special attack is in normal case (capitalized at the beginning of a sentence and otherwise not), and the feat is in title case (each word capitalized).

Now then, about double weapons, two-weapon fighting, and Two-Weapon Fighting.

Strictly speaking, double weapons count as a paired one-handed weapon and light weapon for exactly two purposes:

1. Allowing you to use the two-weapon fighting combat option, treating one end of the double weapon as offhand, and
2. The attack penalties you take when you choose to use that option.

Note that #2 covers Two-Weapon Fighting—it talks about the attack penalties you get when you use two-weapon fighting, for which the double weapon count as paired one-handed and light weapons. And #1 takes care of Improved Two-Weapon Fighting and Greater Two-Weapon Fighting, as those talk about your attacks with your “offhand weapon,” which is one end of your double weapon per the double weapon rules for two-weapon fighting.

For everything aside from those two points, however, and this is being incredibly nit-picky and, frankly, obtuse, the double weapon does **not** count as a one-handed weapon paired with a light weapon—it counts as what it is, which is a two-handed weapon. Including for, say, damage, despite the fact that the rules explicitly highlight the option of *not* using two-weapon fighting in order to get the two-handed weapon damage, and the fact that a prestige class (revenant blade from *Player’s Guide to Eberron*) exists that has the ability to treat each end of a double weapon as a two-handed weapon for damage as its capstone feature.

**This was almost-certainly an oversight.** When you are wielding a double weapon and invoking the two-weapon fighting special attack, you should be treating the ends of the double weapon as a one-handed weapon and a light weapon, respectively. That means that even if a feat fails to specifically say something about double weapons, but instead discusses a pair of weapons, you should feel comfortable letting a double weapon qualify, at least while using the two-weapon fighting special attack. Likewise, things that specify attacking with a two-handed weapon should **not** apply to a double weapon when using the two-weapon fighting special attack (unless you’re a 5th-level revenant blade, of course). But, strict [RAW](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104165/4563), you could argue for the opposite: things for two-handed weapons work with double weapons even while using them for two-weapon fighting, but things for a pair of weapons might not work for double weapons (depending on whether they fall under #1 and/or #2, above, or not), even when using them for two-weapon fighting. This is not recommended.